# Rewriting script so it works without using a temp file

Tags: android, bash, scripting

I have written a small script to pull of all shared object files from an android device for dynamically linked native code development. The script works fine and I could probably stop there, but I don't like the use of the temporary file. I spent some time trying to re-write this so I don't need it but failed with all sorts of attempts. Here is the script:

```
declare -rx OUT_FILE=tmp.sh
adb shell 'cd /system/lib && for f in *.so; do echo -e "adb pull /system/lib/$f ./lib"; done' > $OUT_FILE
dos2unix $OUT_FILE
chmod +x $OUT_FILE
./$OUT_FILE
rm $OUT_FILE
```

I tried using a subshell for the adb command and assigning the result to a variable that could then be fed into sed to strip the carriage returns. I couln't get that to work. Here is an example how I tried using command substitution:

```
res=$(adb shell 'cd /system/lib && for f in *.so; do echo -e "adb pull /system/lib/$f ./lib"; done')
echo $res > tmp.txt
```

Now from my limited knowledge I would suspect that the tmp.txt file from the second solution would contain the same conent as the tmp file in my working solution. This is not the case.

Best Regards,

Andre

Comment: Your script should remove $OUT_FILE, shouldn't it?  Then you can change the name from 'tmp.sh' to 'tmp.$$' or anything else without having to change the last line of your script.  You might also want to investigate 'trap' to ensure that the temp file is removed on interrupt.  All of which adds up to good reasons for wanting to get rid of the temporary file!

Comment: You are right about the rm, that was a copy/paste error...

Comment: The reason the output from your second solution differs is that you didn't quote the variable. Try: `echo "$res" > tmp.txt` and then compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that pipes are supported, then this should work - no intermediate files.  I'm making the wild assumption that 'dos2unix' will work as a pure filter, too.

```
adb shell 'cd /system/lib &&
           for f in *.so; do echo -e "adb pull /system/lib/$f ./lib"; done' |
dos2unix |
bash
```

Answer (score 0):

from all the hints above I managed to distill this:

```
lib_list=$(adb shell 'for f in /system/lib/*.so; do echo $f; done')
for f2 in $lib_list
do
    path=$(echo $f2 | tr -d '\r');
    adb pull $path ./lib
done
```

This works, the main problem was the carriage return. This could nicely by seen by running the script with the -x debugging switch.

Comment: You may wish to add `$'\r'` to `$IFS`. This will allow bash to treat carriage returns as word separators, along with the default of space, tab and newline.